# regex error - nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I get an error message when I use this expression:

```
re.sub(r"([^\s\w])(\s*\1)+","\\1","...")
```

I checked the regex at [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3ctdn) and it returns `.` as expected.  But when I try it in Python I get this error message:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: If anyone gets this error for *no apparent reason*, make sure that the version of Python used when creating your virtualenv still matches the version of the interpreter installed globally (e.g., old vritualenv created before upgrading Python to a newer version.)

Comment: @bvukelic How would I readjust so that they're the same?

Comment: I just destroyed the existing env, and recreated it.

Comment: This is fixed in current version of python and does not throw exception anymore. See [Python Issue18647](https://bugs.python.org/issue18647).

Comment: I had a silly cause of the error where I was matching for a char sequence that began with an asterisk. Escaping the asterisk helped. Check that this is not the issue before concluding that the known Python bug has caused the error.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It seems to be a python bug (that works perfectly in vim).
The source of the problem is the (\s*...)+ bit. Basically , you can't do `(\s*)+` which make sense , because you are trying to repeat something which can be null.

```
>>> re.compile(r"(\s*)+")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 180, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 233, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

However `(\s*\1)` should not be null,  but we know it only because we know what's in \1. Apparently python doesn't ... that's weird.

Comment: @alan: yes, I have noticed that as well.

Comment: @goh: I guess you need to do it in two steps, first remove all the spaces betweens indenticals stuff and then do your previous stuff ,but you won't need anymore the \s* which causes problems.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out a similar issue. For some reason re.compile(mypattern) worked on windows but not linux. Go figure. My issue was I had (.*$)? and had to change it to (.+$)?

Answer (score 23):

That is a Python bug between "*" and special characters.

Instead of

```
re.compile(r"\w*")
```

Try:

```
re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

It works, however does not make the same regular expression.

This bug seems to have been fixed between 2.7.5 and 2.7.6.

Answer (score 13):

It's not only a Python bug with * actually, it can also happen when you pass a string as a part of your regular expression to be compiled, like ;

```
import re
input_line = "string from any input source"
processed_line= "text to be edited with {}".format(input_line)
target = "text to be searched"
re.search(processed_line, target)
```

this will cause an error if processed line contained some "(+)" for example, like you can find in chemical formulae, or such chains of characters.
the solution is to escape but when you do it on the fly, it can happen that you fail to do it properly...

Comment: Yes it can happen with other characters as well. In my case
<re.sub('+','',string)> would break, but <re.sub('\+','', string)> works.

Answer (score 13):

regular expression normally uses * and + in theory of language. 
I encounter the same bug while executing the line code

```
re.split("*",text)
```

to solve it, it needs to include \ before * and +

```
re.split("\*",text)
```

Answer (score 10):

Beyond the bug that was discovered and fixed, I'll just note that the error message `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat` is a bit confusing. I was trying to use `r'?.*'` as a pattern, and thought it was complaining for some strange reason about the `*`, but the problem is actually that `?` is a way of saying "repeat zero or one times". So I needed to say `r'\?.*'`to match a literal `?`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using the regex `\b?`. Using `\s?` fixed the issue (although it's not the same thing)