# Extract data between pound signs

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am parsing through XML files grabbing SQL text and paraments. I need to pull the strings that lie between two # signs. For example if this is my text:

```
CASE WHEN TRIM (NVL (a.SPLR_RMRK, ' ')) = '' OR TRIM (NVL (a.SPLR_RMRK, ' ')) IS NULL THEN '~' ELSE a.SPLR_RMRK END AS TXT_DESCR_J, 'PO' AS TXT_TYP_CD_J FROM #ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME#.P_PO_RCPT_DTL a, (SELECT PO_RCPT_DTL_KEY, ETL_CRT_DTM FROM #ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME#.#jp_PoRcptDtl_Src# WHERE ETL_UPDT_DTM > TO_DATE ('#jp_EtlPrcsDt#', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'))
```

I want to have `ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME`, `ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME` `jp_PoRcptDtl_Src` and `jp_EtlPrcsDt` print out.

Some code that I have so far is

```
for eachLine in testFile:
    print re.findall('#(*?)#', eachLine)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
nothing to repeat.
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to escape `(` and `)` (e.g. `r'\(.*?\)'`).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869650/python-regex-strange-behavior

Comment: Your original sample text had some new line characters. Everything is on one line now?

Comment: No they are on different lines in the actual file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in `bash` regular expressions, the `*` is not a wild-card character, but instead it says *repeat 0 or more times the thing before me*.

In your regular expression, your `*` had no symbol to modify and so you saw the complaint `nothing to repeat`.

**On the other hand**, if you supply a `.` symbol for `*` to modify, testing with one line as an example,

```
eachLine = '#ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME#.P_PO_RCPT_DTL a, (SELECT PO_RCPT_DTL_KEY, '

re.findall('#(.*?)#', eachLine)
```

We get,

```
['ps_RDW_Conn.jp_RDW_SCHEMA_NAME']
```

**Some more detail.**
I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but your `*?` is actually well placed. 
`*?` is interpreted as a single qualifier which says *repeat 0 or more times the thing before me, but take as little as possible*.

So this ends up having the similar effect of what @tobias_k suggests in the comments, in preventing multiple groups from being absorbed into one.

```
>>> line = 'And here is # some interesting code #, where later on there are #fruit flies# ?' 
>>> re.findall('#(.*)#', line)
[' some interesting code #, where later on there are #fruit flies']

>>> 
>>> re.findall('#(.*?)#', line)
[' some interesting code ', 'fruit flies']
>>>
```

For reference, browse [Repeating Things in docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things)

Comment: +1 Don't know why the downvote... however, I'd suggest using `"#([^#]+)#`, so it does not accidentally select more than one group.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not working as intended because you are using both `*` (0 or more) and `?` (0 or 1) to modify the thing before it, but a) there is nothing before it, and b) you should use either `*` or `?`, not both.

If you mean to capture `##` or `#anything#`, then use the regex `#(.*)#`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to escape `(` and `)`. `r'\(.*?\)'` should work.

`for eachLine in testFile:
    print re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', eachLine)`