# How to get rid of specific warning messages in python while keeping all other warnings as normal?

Tags: python

I am doing some simple math recessively in a python script and am getting the follow warning:

> "Warning: divide by zero encountered in divide".

To provide some context, I am taking two values and trying to find the percent difference in value `(a - b) / a` and if its above a certain range then process it, but sometimes the value of `a` or `b` is zero.

I want to get rid of this specific warning (at a specific line) but all the information I have found so far seems to show me how to stop all warnings (which I do not want).

When I used to write shell scripts, I could do something like this

```
code...
more code 2 > error.txt
even more code
```

In that example, I would get the warnings for the 'code' and 'even more code' command but not for the second line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd avoid the division-by-zero in the first place:

```
if a == 0:
    # Break out early

# Otherwise the ratio makes sense
```

If you do want to squash that particular numpy warning on a single line, numpy provides [a way](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html):

```
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    # The problematic line
```

Answer (score 194):

If Scipy is using the `warnings` module, then you can suppress specific warnings.  Try this at the beginning of your program:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="divide by zero encountered in divide")
```

If you want this to apply to only one section of code, then use the warnings context manager:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="divide by zero encountered in divide")
    # .. your divide-by-zero code ..
```

Comment: Nice answer. Actually it took me a surprising amount of googling to find this ultra-simple explanation of how to ignore warnings. @Lostsoul you can use message='regex matching message' to catch warnings by message, and there are also lineno= and module= arguments to catch by line number and module name.

Comment: similarly if there's a category of warnings you want to suppress, replace `message=` with `category=` e.g. `category=FutureWarning`

Comment: For substring: `^.*divide by zero.*$` (regex accepted).

Answer (score 9):

Blenders answer is perfectly fitting the problem. Maybe someone is interested in another general approach to catch specific warnings with either regex or the line number:

surpress a warning caused by a specific line, here line 113:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',lineno=113)
```

This approach has the disadvantage, that each time you change something in the code you need to readjust the lineno. The other option is to catch a warning using regex. The following code will return

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='.*show', )
warnings.warn('Do not do this!')
warnings.warn('Do not show this message')
>>> UserWarning: Do not do this!
        warnings.warn('Do not do this!')
```

The dot before the *-symbol is neccessary as otherwise an error is returned

```
error: nothing to repeat
```

which is discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who by specific warnings mean specific *warning classes* (*categories* in warning handling jargon), then you can pass the category to be suppressed to the `category` parameter of the [`simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) or [`filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) function:

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=Warning)
```