# How to disable Python warnings?

Tags: python, suppress-warnings

I am working with code that throws a lot of (for me at the moment) useless warnings using the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) library. Reading (/scanning) the documentation I only found a way [to disable warnings for single functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings). But I don't want to change so much of the code.

Is there a flag like `python -no-warning foo.py`?

What would you recommend?

Comment: @MartinSamson I generally agree, but there are legitimate cases for ignoring warnings. I get several of these from using the valid Xpath syntax in defusedxml: `FutureWarning: This search is broken in 1.3 and earlier, and will be fixed in a future version.  If you rely on the current behaviour, change it to [this other thing]`. I would rather ignore the warnings now and wait for it to be silently fixed than write needlessly ugly code just to avoid a harmless warning.

Comment: disable specific warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134795/how-to-get-rid-of-specific-warning-messages-in-python-while-keeping-all-other-wa

Comment: "Python doesn't throw around warnings for no reason."  But some developers do.  I am using a module that throws a useless warning despite my completely valid usage of it.

Answer (score 687, accepted):

There's the [`-W` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w).

```
python -W ignore foo.py
```

Comment: To ignore only specific message you can add details in parameter. `man python` describes it in details excepts module name specification. I spent much time guessing it. Finally i got this command `python3 -W ignore::UserWarning:git.cmd:914 ./test.py` for warning `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/git/cmd.py:914: UserWarning: Python 3.5 support is deprecated...`

Comment: If using ipython is there a way to do this when calling a function?

Answer (score 1145):

Look at the [Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) section of the Python docs:

> If you are using code that you know will raise a warning, such as a deprecated function, but do not want to see the warning, then it is possible to suppress the warning using the [`catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) context manager:
>
> ```
> import warnings
>
> def fxn():
>     warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
>
> with warnings.catch_warnings():
>     warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
>     fxn()
>
> # Or if you are using > Python 3.11:
> with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore"):
>     fxn()
> ```

I don't condone it, but you could just **suppress all warnings** with this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Ex:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> def f():
...     print('before')
...     warnings.warn('you are warned!')
...     print('after')
...
>>> f()
before
<stdin>:3: UserWarning: you are warned!
after
>>> warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
>>> f()
before
after
```

Comment: So you have to wrap the code in each file with a `with warnings.catch_warnings():`?

Comment: @Framester - yes, IMO this is the cleanest way to suppress specific warnings, warnings are there in general because something could be wrong, so suppressing all warnings via the command line might not be the best bet.

Comment: @Framester - I listed the other option with an example as well... I don't like it as much (for reason I gave in the previous comment) but at least now you have the tools.

Comment: If you only expect to catch warnings from a specific category, you can pass it using the `category` argument: `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: This is useful for me in this case because html5lib spits out lxml warnings even though it is not parsing xml. Thanks

Comment: There is also a useful parameter for the `warnings.filterwarnings`  function: `module`. It allows you to ignore warnings from specified module.

Comment: Re-iterating what worked along with the advice above: As mentioned in another post/comment, this solution should be implemented/added much before importing the library/function causing the warning.
Nice approach would be to include it at the beginning of the program where we have import statements.

Comment: Your example of the right way to do things is not useful without further explanation.  For example, do you insert your code in fxn() before or after warning.warn?  Does this work in a multiprocessing example?  Who knows?  The python docs don't seem to help here and I didn't get this working in my code.  The comment by -ostrokach works and requires no further explanation.

Comment: For Python 3.11 and above, simply `with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore", category=WarningToBeIgnored):`

Answer (score 210):

Not to make it complicated, just use these two lines on the top

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Answer (score 184):

You can also define an environment variable (new feature in 2010 - i.e. python 2.7)

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"
```

Test like this: *Default*

```
$ export PYTHONWARNINGS="default"
$ python
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn('my warning')
__main__:1: UserWarning: my warning
>>>
```

*Ignore* warnings

```
$ export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"
$ python
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn('my warning')
>>>
```

For **deprecation warnings** have a look at [how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python)

Copied here...

From documentation of the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

If you're on Windows: pass `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning` as an argument to Python. Better though to resolve the issue, by casting to [int](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#int).

(Note that in Python 3.2, deprecation warnings are ignored by default.)

Or:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    import md5, sha

yourcode()
```

Now you still get all the other `DeprecationWarning`s, but not the ones caused by:

```
import md5, sha
```

Comment: This is especially useful to ignore warnings when performing tests. Using `tox`, adding `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore` to `setenv` makes output less dirty.

Comment: Very useful for AWS CLI as well.

Comment: But this doesn't ignore the deprecation warning. May I ask how to include that one?

Comment: since I am loading environment variables for other purposes in my .env file I added the line `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore` and it worked like a charm (works for python 3.10)

Answer (score 144):

If you don't want something complicated, then:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```

Comment: And to turn things back to the default behavior: `warnings.filterwarnings("default", category=FutureWarning)`

Answer (score 115):

When all else fails use this: https://github.com/polvoazul/shutup

`pip install shutup`

then add to the top of your code:

```py
import shutup; shutup.please()
```

---

*Disclaimer:* I am the owner of that repository. I wrote it after the 5th time I needed this and couldn't find anything simple that just worked.

Answer (score 96):

This is an old question but there is some newer guidance in [PEP 565](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0565) that to turn off all warnings if you're writing a python application you should use:

```
import sys
import warnings

if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

The reason this is recommended is that it turns off all warnings by default but crucially allows them to be switched back on via `python -W` on the command line or `PYTHONWARNINGS`.

Comment: This is perfect since it will not disable all warnings in later execution

Answer (score 53):

If you know what are the useless warnings you usually encounter, you can filter them by message.

```
import warnings

#ignore by message
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="divide by zero encountered in divide")

##part of the message is also okay
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="divide by zero encountered") 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="invalid value encountered")
```

Answer (score 18):

```
import sys
if not sys.warnoptions:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

Change `ignore` to `default` when working on the file or adding new functionality to re-enable warnings.

Answer (score 7):

I realise this is only applicable to a niche of the situations, but within a `numpy` context I really like using [`np.errstate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html):

```py
np.sqrt(-1)
```

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
nan
```

However, using `np.errstate`:

```py
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    np.sqrt(-1)
```

```
nan
```

The best part being you can apply this to very specific lines of code only.

Answer (score 5):

---

### More pythonic way to ignore **WARNINGS**

---

Since '*warning.filterwarnings()*' is not suppressing all the warnings, i will suggest you to use the following method:

```
import logging
    
for name in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys():
    logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

#rest of the code starts here...
```

**OR,**

If you want to suppress only a *specific* set of warnings, then you can filter like this:

```
import logging
    
for name in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys():
    if ('boto' in name) or ('urllib3' in name) or ('s3transfer' in name) or ('boto3' in name) or ('botocore' in name) or ('nose' in name):
            logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

#rest of the code starts here...
```

Comment: The wording is confusing, but there's 2 kinds of "warnings" and the one mentioned by OP isn't put into `logging` unless you call `logging.captureWarnings(True)`.  They're specifically talking about the `warnings` module that outputs to STDERR and not logging messages with level `WARNING`.

Answer (score 5):

For example you can ignore this warning:

**InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host...**

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(
    action="ignore",
    message=".*Unverified HTTPS.*",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a decorator that makes it very easy to ignore warnings only in specific function definitions:

```
import functools
import warnings

from typing import Callable

def ignore_warnings(category: Warning):
    def ignore_warnings_decorator(func: Callable):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=category)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return ignore_warnings_decorator
```

Example usage:

```py
@ignore_warnings(category=DeprecationWarning)
def foo() -> None:
    # imagine this function below would throw a deprecation
    # warning that we willfully want to ignore because we know better:
    bar()
```

Answer (score -11):

Warnings are output via stderr and the simple solution is to append  to the command.

`2> /dev/null`

Alternatively, redirect errors to a file, so they are retained without dirtying the console output.

`2> my-cli-errors.log`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Please keep answers strictly on-topic though: You mention quite a few things which are irrelevant to the question as it currently stands, such as CentOS, Python 2.6, cryptography, the urllib, back-porting. You can edit your question to remove those bits. If you want to know more details from the OP, leave a comment under the question instead.