# How to suppress warning when executing Python code from within VIM

Tags: python, linux, unix, editor, vi

When running the code from comman line I have no problem:

```
$ python mycode.py > output.txt
```

But running that very code from within VI editor raises warning:

```
:! python mycod.py > output.txt
/opt6/tools/python2.6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/oldnumeric/__init__.py:11: ModuleDeprecationWarning: The oldnumeric module will be dropped in Numpy 1.9
  warnings.warn(_msg, ModuleDeprecationWarning)
```

Why is that and how to disable that from VI?

Comment: `python -W ignore mycode.py > output.txt` but this is a duplicated question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable python warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: Strange. The warning should be produced even when running `python` on the console. Are you sure that you are running the same python version? If I'm not mistaken starting from python 2.7 deprecation warnings are ignored by default.

Answer (score 0):

manage the numpy warnings with seterr :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html