# How do I block python RuntimeWarning from printing to the terminal?

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

I have some python code that, at some point, takes the axis means of a reasonably sparse array with nans in. Every time I run the code it raises a `RuntimeWarning`.

I know what's causing the warning, it's intentional, and it doesn't affect the output. It is, however, quite irritating to be presented with the warning every time I run the program - so, is there a cheap and nasty way to prevent them from being printed to the terminal?

Comment: Run your main script using the -W option like this: **python -W ignore your_script.py**

Comment: if it is written (as should be) to stderr then you can add `2>/dev/null` to call

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may be useful to you, I think the issue has been pretty solved in this question: [How to disable python warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Answer (score 4):

All what you need is suppress it exactly as described in official documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings