# Ignore divide by 0 warning in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, suppress-warnings, divide-by-zero

I have a function for statistic issues:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma as Gamma

def Foo(xdata):
    ...
    return x1 * (
                 ( #R is a numpy vector
                  ( ((R - x2)/beta) ** (x3 -1) ) * 
                  ( np.exp( - ((R - x2) / x4) ) ) /
                  ( x4 * Gamma(x3))
                 ).real
                )
```

Sometimes I get from the shell the following warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in...
```

I use the numpy `isinf` function to correct the results of the function in other files, so I do not need this warning.

Is there a way to ignore the message?
In other words, I do not want the shell to print this message.

I do not want to disable all python warnings, just this one.

Comment: You could just catch it and ignore it if you don't need to recover from it.

Comment: you can always use `try... except ZeroDivisionError` (or whatever error is being thrown)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable python warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: @letsc no error is being thrown.  the OP is getting a warning.

Comment: marsh I don't want to disable all the warning. Just this if it's possible.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can disable the warning with [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html). Put this before the possible division by zero:

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore')
```

That'll disable zero division warnings globally. If you just want to disable them for a little bit, you can use [`numpy.errstate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) in a `with` clause:

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    # some code here
```

---

For a zero by zero division (undetermined, results in a NaN), the error behaviour has changed with numpy version 1.8.0: this is now considered "invalid", while previously it was "divide".

Thus, if there is a chance you your numerator could be zero as well, use

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```

or

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    # some code here
```

See the "Compatibility" section in the  [release notes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.8.0-notes.html#runtime-warnings-when-comparing-nan-numbers), last paragraph before the "New Features" section:

> Comparing `NaN` floating point numbers now raises the `invalid` runtime warning. If a `NaN` is expected the warning can be ignored using np.errstate.

Answer (score -3):

You could also use `numpy.divide` for division. That way you don't have to explicitly disable warnings.

```
In [725]: np.divide(2, 0)
Out[725]: 0
```

Comment: This is actually not true. At least, for NumPy version 1.15.4

Comment: No longer true. This now returns inf