# how to avoid division by zero in 2d numpy array when taking average?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have three arrays

```
A = np.array([[2,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,2,1]])
B = np.array([[2,0,2],[0,1,0],[1,2,1]])
C = np.array([[2,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,2]])
A,B,C
(array([[2, 2, 2],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 1]]),
 array([[2, 0, 2],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 2, 1]]),
 array([[2, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 2]]))
```

when i take average of C/ (A+B), i get nan/inf value with RunTimeWarning..
the resultant array looks like the following.

```
np.average(C/(A+B), axis = 1)
array([0.25      ,        nan, 0.58333333])
```

I would like to change any inf/nan value to 0.

What I tried so far was

```
#doesn't work. ( maybe im doing this wrong..)
mask = A+B >0
np.average(C[mask]/(A[mask]+B[mask]), axis = 1)


#does not work and not an ideal solution.
avg = np.average(C/(A+B), axis = 1)
avg[avg == np.nan] =0
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950557/ignore-divide-by-0-warning-in-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tried approaches are both a valid way of dealing with it, but you need to change them slightly.

1. Avoiding the division upfront, by only calculating the result where it's valid (eg non-zero):

The use of the boolean mask you defined makes the resulting arrays (after indexing) to become 1D. So using this would mean you have to allocate the resulting array upfront, and assign it using that same mask.

```py
mask = A+B > 0
result = np.zeros_like(A, dtype=np.float32)
result[mask] = C[mask]/(A[mask]+B[mask])
```

It does require the averaging over the second dimension to be done separate, and also masking the incorrect result to zero for elements where the division could not be done due to the zeros.

```py
result = result.mean(axis=1)
result[(~mask).any(axis=1)] = 0
```

To me the main benefit would be avoiding the warning from Numpy, and perhaps in the case of a large amount of zeros (in A+B) you could gain a little performance by avoiding that calculation all together. But overall it seems a lot of effort to me.

2. Masking invalid values afterwards:

The main takeaway here is that you should **never ever** compare against `np.nan` directly since it will always be False. You can check this yourself by looking at the result from `np.nan == np.nan`. The way to handle this is use the dedicated `np.isnan` function. Or alternatively negate the `np.isfinite` function if you also want to catch +/- `np.inf` values at the same time.

```py
avg = np.average(C/(A+B), axis = 1)
avg[np.isnan(avg)] = 0

# or to include inf
avg[~np.isfinite(avg)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, np.nan])
print(a) # [1, nan]
a = np.nan_to_num(a)
print(a) # [1, 0]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

for `inf` and `-inf`

```
from numpy import inf
avg[avg == inf] = 0
avg[avg == -inf] = 0
```

Comment: how do we avoid error and division by 0 in first place ( maybe via using mask?) rather than changing nan to 0 or inf/-inf to 0?

Comment: warnings, not errors. Just read the thread posted by @Nick on how to disable them.

Comment: Yes disable warnings and replacing to 0 helps but is there a way doing this using a mask or some otherway around? Im just trying to scratch my head to do this without using disable warnings and replace to 0..

Comment: You have `0`s in your input arrays so the only thing is to remove them before applying the `average`, but it's your input and you can't change it... You can try to implement the division of arrays and the average by yourself with some `if` to avoid division by `0`, but I can't see any benefit of it. Just disable warnings..

Answer (score 0):

This is tougher than I thought as `np.mean`'s `where` argument doesn't work if it results in empty arrays and `np.average`'s `weights` have to be 1-D.

```py
# these don't work
# >>> np.mean(div, axis=1, where=mask.all(1, keepdims=True))
# RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

# >>> np.average(div, axis=1, weights=mask.all(1, keepdims=True))
# TypeError: 1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.

import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,2,1]])
B = np.array([[2,0,2],[0,1,0],[1,2,1]])
C = np.array([[2,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,2]])

div = np.zeros(C.shape)
AB = A+B                                # avoid repeated summing
mask = AB > 0                           # AB != 0 to include all valid divisors
np.divide(C, AB, where=mask, out=div)   # out=None won't initialize unused elements
np.mean(div * mask.all(1, keepdims=True), axis = 1)
```

Output

```
array([0.25      , 0.        , 0.58333333])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow this if you are supposed to keep the inf value zero

```
np.divide(a, b, where=b.astype(bool))
```

Comment: this use of `where` also requires an `out` parameter.