# FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning with Flask_Security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am received a warning every time I use Flask Security.

```
FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.Form" has been renamed to "FlaskForm" 
and will be removed in 1.0.
```

Is this an issue with Flask Security or something I could address myself? I am using Flask-Security==1.7.5

```
from flask_security import current_user, login_required, RoleMixin, Security, \
SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, utils
```

I don't seem to import Flask_WTF directly.

Comment: Short answer: it's Flask-Security, but it is something you could address yourself by updating the library. Feel free to comment on my answer below if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like 1.7.5 is the latest release of Flask-Security.  And the latest version of Flask-WTF is 0.13 (make sure you have that installed by checking a `pip freeze`).

Since you don't use Flask-WTF directly, the issue isn't your code.  The issue is coming from Flask-Security's code itself, [which has Flask-WTF as a dependency](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/1.7.5/requirements.txt).

The way that Flask-Security imports the Form class from Flask-WTF is deprecated, so you're seeing the error when this line runs:

```
from flask_wtf import Form as BaseForm
```

https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/e01cd63a214969cf8e4ee800d398e1c43b460c7f/flask_security/forms.py#L15

You can either open an issue on Flask-Security (feel free to link to this question) or submit a pull request yourself to the author updating this line to the non-deprecated import

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as BaseForm
```

Make sure to run tests before / after too before submitting.

For a little more context, you can use git blame to see the commit that last changed the deprecated import line in Flask-Security ([6f68f1d](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/commit/6f68f1d540502a1747cae87f0ffa2332cb4e2c94)) on August 15, 2013.

Doing the same on Flask-WTF, you can see that the deprecation was introduced in [42cc475](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/commit/42cc47562abf817c751ff22debbd9032a3c3f45d) on June 30, 2016.

Comment: I should point out that you also have various options for just suppressing the warnings without modifying Flask-Security (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings).  Still updating it helps the whole community so everyone doesn't have to suppress the same warning.

Answer (score 11):

My answer is **not** inherent to your exact situation. However, the same warning message occurs when we code this:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
```

To fix this problem, you should use `FlaskForm` in place of `Form`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```

This is highlighted on [GitHub](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/265) and I just want to share the solution here to help any eventual doer who might face it in the future.