# SQLAlchemy decimal truncation

Tags: python, mysql, casting, sqlalchemy

I want to insert values into a table (MySQL), where a field is defined as

```
Column('profit', DECIMAL(8, 2), nullable=False)
```

The values being inserted are Python floats (stored in a `DataFrame`, from Pandas library).  When I do this with SQLAlchemy, I'm getting a warning:

> Warning: Data truncated for column 'profit' at row 124

What do I have to do to avoid this warning? I don't see a way to use Python's `Decimal` class here because the table may contain decimals with different precision, baring that any operation on instances of this class will be very slow and far too cumbersome.

Comment: Then why use a `DECIMAL` in the db? Why not a `FLOAT`?

Comment: @user2722968 because this is how the table is defined. The definition of the table isn't under my control.

Comment: Then you are out of options - the floats will get truncated.

Comment: @user2722968 sure, that's not a problem. I just want to suppress the warning since it pollutes the log. In other words: I can convert the values in the `DataFrame` before insertion into something that won't generate the warning. I understand that the loss of precision is inevitable in this situation. To give an example: I could convert all floats to strings having representation with desired precision, but I hoped there is a way to just dismiss the warning rather than doing a massive conversion.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is: why are they `float`s in the first place?

Comment: @univerio that's not something I can influence: they come from some JSON-encoded request, where there are no decimal types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable python warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: @IljaEverilä the warning comes from SQL, not from Python.

Comment: Ah, sorry failed to read with thought. Still, I'd think it is translated to a python warning, or is it not?

Comment: @IljaEverilä not that I can see, and I don't want to disable it in general. I would be interested to disable it per specific column in the database, not per Python function.

Comment: You can [parse JSON numbers as decimals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) (`json.loads(..., parse_float=decimal.Decimal)`).