# How to disable imported module logging at root level

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm importing a module that is logging information at a warning level. I think that the person who wrote this code is logging at a root level i.e. in the code is just:

```
import logging
logging.warn("foo")
```

I've tried the below code but it doesn't work, probably because the logging is sent to root or something.

```
logging.getLogger(module).setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Is there a way that I could disable this module's specific logging?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things confusing here:

```
logging.getLogger(module).setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

The ‘module’ here should be a string, and is usually the full-qualified name of the module. Ie: `package.module`.

Depending of the format, the name of the Logger is usually printed in the log. That way you can disable it easily.

For instance, if you have something like:

```
WARNING [foo.bar.baz] the message
```

The logger name should be `foo.bar.baz`.

But, if you think it is the root logger, then you can try:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger .setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Another thing which can be confusing, is the Python warnings. Take a look at this answer to disable them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362