# Python statmodels lib deprecation warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics, time-series

I am doing some statistical tests using the Dickey-Fuller method.

After I made the import:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
```

I am receiving this `FutureWarning`:

> /env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/compat/pandas.py:56:
>   FutureWarning: The pandas.core.datetools module is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version. Please use the pandas.tseries module
>   instead.   from pandas.core import datetools

The thing is I can't find the implementation for the `adfuller()` in `pandas.tseries` as mentioned in the deprecation warning.

Statsmodels version is `statsmodels==0.8.0`

Any clues how to solve this?

Comment: What version of statsmodels are you using? It looks like this has already been fixed: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/3618.

Comment: Hi! It's statsmodels==0.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3617) this was fixed in `statsmodels==0.9`, so you should upgrade if possible. If you can't upgrade for whatever reason [there are ways to suppress warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) so at least you won't have to see them all the time.