# deprecation error in sklearn about empty array without any empty array in my code

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I am just playing around encoding and decoding but I get this error from sklearn:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 151
>       if diff:
>   DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.

Here is the full code, you can run it yourself in python 3+

My question is why is it saying I use an empty array as I clearly don't in my code, thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

```
### label encoding ###

import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Sample input labels
input_labels = ["red", "black", "red", "green",\
                "black", "yellow", "white"]

# Create label encoder abd fit the label
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(input_labels)

# Print the mapping
print("\nLabel mapping:")
for i, item in enumerate(encoder.classes_):
    print(item, "-->", i)

# Encode a set of labels using encoder
test_labels = ["green", "red", "black"]
encoded_values = encoder.transform(test_labels)
print("\nLabels =", test_labels)
print("Encoded values =", list(encoded_values))

# Decode a set of values using the encoder
encoded_values = [3, 0, 4, 1]
decoded_list = encoder.inverse_transform(encoded_values)
print("\nEncoded values =", encoded_values)
print("Decoded labels=", list(decoded_list))
```

Comment: What's your sklearn version? I don't get the warning on *0.18.1* (and numpy *1.13.3*).

Comment: sklearn is version 0.19.1 and numpy is 1.14.0

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TLDR: You can ignore the warning. It is caused by sklearn doing something internally that is not quite ideal.

---

The warning is actually caused by `numpy`, which [deprecated truth testing on empty arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9583):

> The long and short is that truth-testing on empty arrays is dangerous, misleading, and not in any way useful, and should be deprecated.

This means one is not supposed to do something like `if array:` to check if `array` is empty. However, sklearn [does this in the 0.19.1 release](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.19.1/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L151):

```
    diff = np.setdiff1d(y, np.arange(len(self.classes_)))
    if diff:
        raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" % str(diff))
```

Because your version of numpy is recent enough it complains and issues a warning.

The problem [has been fixed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/c554aad456b6302a8dd8838769769eeecc1cf734) in sklearn's current master branch, so I'd expect the fix to be included in the next release.

Comment: You could suppress this specific warning, like shown in the first of 3 code blocks from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/4057186).

Answer (score 1):

After updated numpy, the warning was cleared away:

```
conda update numpy
```

You can also update it by pip or something else.