# lambdification of sympy piecewise function evaluates every expression

Tags: python, sympy, piecewise, lambdify

I'm lambdifying a sympy piecewise function trying to do something like this:

```
f = Piecewise((1,(p > -1e-10) & (p < 1e-10)), (1/p, True))
g = lambdify(p,f,"numpy")
```

While

```
>>> f.subs(p,0)
1
```

I get

```
>>> g(0)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  """ 
array(1.0)
```

It seems, that (the lambdified ?)-Piecewise evaluates all expressions before returning the one with the true condition. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's been a while since I used sympy. Would `p != 0  and 1/p` instead of `1/p` be valid?

Comment: It is valid in the Piecewise Definition, but after lambdification it seems I have the same problem.

Comment: that's odd. If `p != 0 and 1/p`, normally that would only evaluate `1/p` if `p!=0` was `False`. Still, sympy is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [NumPy code printer used by lambdify](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/pycode.py#L330) translates `Piecewise` to

```
numpy.select(conditions, expressions, default=numpy.nan)
```

This means that the array `expressions` is computed in its entirety before `numpy.select` selects one element of that array.  Some ways to get around it are:

1) **Change the backend** to `math` (or `mpmath`, or anything other than `numpy`), which will cause `Piecewise` to be translated as a [nested if statement](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/pycode.py#L141).

```
g = lambdify(p, f, "math")
g(0)  # 1, no warnings
```

2) **Rewrite the formula** in terms of Max/Min/Abs/sign, which can express some piecewise functions and lambdify easily. This isn't always possible but in your case,

```
f = 0.5 * (sign(p + 1e-10) + sign(p - 1e-10)) / Max(1e-10, Abs(p)) + 0.5 * (sign(p + 1e-10) - sign(p - 1e-10))
```

does the job.  The trick is that `0.5 * (sign(p + 1e-10) + sign(p - 1e-10))` is sign(p) when p is not too close to 0, and is 0 when it is. Similarly, `0.5 * (sign(p + 1e-10) - sign(p - 1e-10))` is 1 if p is not too close to 0 and is 0 when it is. These factors cause the formula to switch from one mode to the other, and `Max` in the denominator avoids the division by zero error in any case.

3) [**Suppress Runtime Warnings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: Great offer of choices. I was trying to do something like in 2) but I find 1) much more convenient. I'm doing it with mpmath now. Thank you.