# How do I remove the warnings that arise in GuidedLDA's implementation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The warning that I am receiving is this:
**WARNING:guidedlda:all zero column in document-term matrix found**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

Comment: I already tried all the solutions mentioned in that post, none of them seem to solve this particular warning.