# the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib

Tags: python, imp

I use sublime , this is my code:[image]

when I build it, it warning: [image]

and my python version is 3.6.4.

how could i do? thank you!

Comment: Please, post code as code and text as text, not as photographs of code and photographs of text. This is a programming website, not a photography website, we want to copy&paste&read&debug your code, not critique its use of color and perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a warning, and it's in a module that isn't written by you, so you can either upgrade your dependencies to try to resolve it, or ignore it, or filter it out using the `warnings` module: [How to disable python warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)