# What's a generic fix for this problem – "RuntimeWarning: compiletime version X of module ABC does not match runtime version Y"?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error, miniconda

I ran into this problem:

```
RuntimeWarning: compiletime version X of module ABC does not match runtime version Y
```

And I'm unable to import the module, presumably as a result of this. More specifically, I get the following error immediately after:

```
stop [Error]:
    No stopped context was found!
```

I have found a lot of program/package specific questions addressing this problem on Stack Overflow, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225210/tensorflow-install-fails-with-compiletime-version-3-5-of-module-does-not-match) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716020/how-to-ignore-or-fix-runtimewarning-compiletime-version), but not a generic fix.

*Is* there a generic fix to this, or advice for some place/thing I should look into when this happens? Or is this just a case-by-case problem which there's no generic suggestions for?

Any advice would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because i'm unable to import the module as a result of this.

Comment: The error says the module was compiled for different version of python that it's executed in. It's a warning, not error, because it can theoretically run but you can run into problems, so you should know it.

Comment: `because i'm unable to import the module as a result of this` - how? Does it say anything else? Because that's just a warning, you should be able to use your import normally after that

Comment: I get a stop error: ```stop [Error]:
    No stopped context was found!```

Comment: well, then you may need to update the version or get the same version which btw is the general fix anyways

Comment: How/where would I do this? I'm using conda, if it helps.

Comment: Please also say what lib is that and what versions. We're no longer looking for generic solution, we're investigating your case with specific lib. Is that NEST? Because googling that message gives me only NEST results, but often in the middle of other problems

Comment: You're correct, it is NEST. A lib-specific solution would be great. I was asking for a generic version just so I would know what to do if I run into this in the future in another context.