# Silence UndefinedMetricWarning

Tags: scikit-learn, suppress-warnings

I have really a lot of `UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.` resulting from running a randomized search pipeline with cross-validation. I know what is causing this behavior and suggested setting to 0.0 score is currently fine with me, so I want to just silence this warning for now.

I tried:

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

and

```
from sklearn.exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UndefinedMetricWarning)
```

But I am still getting these warnings, even though other answers on StackOverflow suggested that they should be suppressed by these lines (and actually it worked for me some time ago in a notebook).

The `warnings.filterwarnings(...)` line is located directly under `import` statements, and the warnings are from in one of the nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
from sklearn.exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning

def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn

# more code here...
# more code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution in the question works:

```
from sklearn.exceptions import UndefinedMetricWarning
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UndefinedMetricWarning)
```

also see:
[How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

I am using this:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) 
>>> print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
The scikit-learn version is 1.0.1.
```