# Manage warnings in a python package

Tags: python, import, package, warnings, suppress-warnings

I am working on a python library where we sometimes display user warnings using pythons warnings module.
We now want to be able to turn off all of this warnings based on a flag passed to the python interpreter.

I read that the `__init__` files are actually called first when importing a library but putting

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

in the highest level `__init__.py` does not change anything.

Are these options only for the current file?
I am looking for a place where I can turn off all warnings in the library, because I don't want to manage this in every single file separately.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter Notebook, you can try this:-
Go to the '/home/user/.ipython/profile_default/startup/start.py' and load this module(If start.py is not present create one.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to be surprised if this turns out to be horribly unpythonic, but for a similar issue (common formatting across modules) I have in `__init__.py`:

```py
def warning_on_one_line(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    return '%s:%s: %s: %s\n' % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)

warnings.formatwarning = warning_on_one_line
```

And then in submodules:

```py
from package_name import warnings
```

That brings the changes made in `__init__.py` with it to all submodules.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but I guess it is still rather annoying having to provide this in every submodule.