# restarting main.py without circular import error

Tags: python

I am trying to restart my main.py after the program has finished running. However, when I go into the last file (unlock.py) then put at the end of the script:

```
from main import *

main()
```

I get a circular import error. I am not sure a way to work around this so if anyone knows, your help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: why are you importing a module at the end of the script?

Comment: @sage07 to restart the program as main.py is the runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `execv` method of `os` module:

```py
import os
import sys

os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

If you're getting any permission errors:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
```

To disable warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: Though you'll need to replace `__file__` with `'main.py'`.

Comment: It will work because the `__file__` contains the name of the file we're running.

Comment: Right but he'd be calling `os.execv` from unlock.py.

Comment: do I need to import anything for this?

Comment: this works but I get this error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: Is main.py executable or are you invoking it with the Python interpreter explicitly?

Comment: I did chmod +x main.py
now I get this error: Exec format error @DanielWalker

Comment: I get this error: `UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '`
@YogeshDeveloper

Comment: It's just a warning of using extra resources. Program ran?

Comment: Thank you! It is working but is there a way to get that warning to not display? @YogeshDeveloper

Comment: I definitely will accept, except the warning is still showing. This is what my code looks like:
import time
import sys
import os
import warnings



`def redo(): 
    time.sleep(5)
    os.execv(sys.executable, 
            [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'main.py')] + sys.argv[1:])
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`

Comment: You should add the warning filter at the top of your code

Comment: I added it just below my imports and it is still not working...

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the structure of your program, the best recommendation I can give is to pass your `main` function around as an argument.  That way, in unlock.py, you don't need to import the `main` module.

Consider this simple example:

**main.py**

```
import unlock

def main(function_to_pass):
    # do stuff
    unlock.some_func(function_to_pass,*rest_of_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(main)
```

**unlock.py**

```
def some_func(function_to_call,*args):
   # do stuff
   if some_condition:
        function_to_call()
```

EDIT: I realized that you don't need to pass `main` into itself.  `main` can simply reference itself.  That is,

```
def main():
    # do stuff
    unlock.some_func(main,*args)
```

Comment: can you expand on this? I am a bit confused