# How can I suppress warnings when running a python script?

Tags: python, warnings

I am trying to suppress warnings.

here is my esri python version

python -V

Python 2.7.16

I have tried this

python.exe -W ignore GET_ESRIGIS_WEB_TOKEN.py

but it gives this error

Invalid -W option ignored: invalid action: '"ignore'

what am I doing wrong?

ps: here is the help (see -W option below)

```
python.exe -h
```

**-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg**

```
usage: python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-b     : issue warnings about comparing bytearray with unicode
         (-bb: issue errors)
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
-O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : remove doc-strings in addition to the -O optimizations
-R     : use a pseudo-random salt to make hash() values of various types be
         unpredictable between separate invocations of the interpreter, as
         a defense against denial-of-service attacks
-Q arg : division options: -Qold (default), -Qwarn, -Qwarnall, -Qnew
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-S     : don't imply 'import site' on initialization
-t     : issue warnings about inconsistent tab usage (-tt: issue errors)
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg
-x     : skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd
-3     : warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix
file   : program read from script file
-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)
arg ...: arguments passed to program in sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: That's strange. `-W ignore` is the proper way to do it. It works on my python2 linux installation if that's any consolation!

Comment: Any chance you've got the wrong `warnings` module? Write a little script that imports and prints `warnings.__file__`.

Comment: Do you have a `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable? Perhaps that is misformatted. Maybe there is something odd about this "esri" python build... whatever that is. Its a coursework thing? Maybe they disable it in the their build?

Answer (score 9):

Usually `python -W ignore file.py` should work.

However, you can try adding this to the code as well to suppress all warnings

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/3288888

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
-Wignore
```

without space. f.e.:

```
python -Wignore file.py
```