# How to avoid warning in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a questions about Pandas.

I wrote a following code :

```
df_all.loc[df_all['_merge'] == 'right_only', ['count', 'Discount', 'RefPrice']] = df_all.loc[df_all['_merge'] == 'right_only', ['old_count', 'old_Discount', 'old_RefPrice']].values
```

However, Python returns a warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
    File "C:\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472
        return self._getitem_tuple(key)
FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
    
See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
```

What can I do to avoid this warning?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [How to disable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: This error occurs because one of the columns in your list is not in your DataFrame.

Comment: Did you try to look at the documentation at the web page address shown in the message?

Comment: Essentially, see why you are trying to index a column that doesn't exist.