# Can't suppress fasttext warning: 'load_model' does not return [...]

Tags: python, warnings, fasttext

I'm struggling to suppress a specific warning related to `fasttext`.

The warning is `Warning : 'load_model' does not return WordVectorModel or SupervisedModel any more, but a 'FastText' object which is very similar.`

And here is the offending block of code:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    return fasttext.load_model(str(model_path))  # this line
```

I've attempted several ways to suppress the warning, mostly from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) without success.

I'm using `Python 3.8`, `fasttext v0.9.2`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For `fasttext v0.9.2` this can be solved by adding the monkey patch below to your code ([as per this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1067)).

```py
import fasttext

fasttext.FastText.eprint = lambda x: None
```

As mentioned in that same GitHub issue, the warning message was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/commit/9ef22d9fac33c84480fa2e4edf56df13cb0bcfbb) in May 2020, which will likely be in the next official release (v0.9.3), whenever that is.

Comment: It's been over 3 years and it's still showing up, pretty annoying ngl. Thanks for the monkey patch.

Comment: Thank you, I found this to be useful in 2024.