# Function returning either 0 or -inf without warning

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

I am trying to write a function that takes the log of a boolean expression `np.log(bool_variable)`. Basically I want the function to return `0` if `bool_variable=True` or `-np.inf` if `bool_variable=False`. One easy way would be to use an if statement, but this could slow things down. Is there a way for me to use the function below and avoid the warning `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` ONLY IN THIS FUNCTION? That is, I want this function to suppress that warning, but I would still like any other piece of code in the script to raise that warning if it happens.

```py
def function(x):
    return np.log(x <= 2)
```

Ideally I will be running a similar function many many times, so I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011115/3001761, in your case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this does not work within a function. Try this MWN:

`def function(x):
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
        return np.log(x<= 2)
`
Running ```function(3)``` raises the warning

Comment: Actually yes it does, just need `divide='ignore'`