# Non literal import Untrusted user input in importlib.import_module() Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, whitelist, semgrep

I am getting below warning while running my python code through Semgrep(Static Code validater).
Please suggest any practical example how  to use a whitelist to prevent running untrusted code or any other solution to avoid this warning.I searched on net but could not found any example..

I am getting warning at below particuklar line with import_module

Warning:
Untrusted user input in importlib.import_module() function allows an attacker to load arbitrary code.Avoid dynamic values in importlib.import_module() or use a whitelist to prevent running untrusted code.

```
channel_module = import_module("src.main.core_prj.prj_" + config['subscription'].lower())
```

Comment: You're getting this warning because dynamically importing modules like that is a real security risk. You could just suppress the warning with some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) but I would recommend re-thinking this piece of code (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

The triggered rule can be found at https://semgrep.dev/r?q=Untrusted+user+input+in+importlib.import_module .  Clicking on the rule will expand to show the definition, which shows it allows `importlib.import_module("..")` and triggers a warning if a variable is used.

The rule mentions it is intending to prevent [CWE-706: Use of Incorrectly-Resolved Name or Reference](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/706.html), which is quite broad.

This is not relevant in the sample code, which has a string prefix before the user defined config string, so there is no opportunity that `import_module("src.main.core_prj.prj_" + config['subscription'].lower())` will load a module (resource) that is outside of the intended control sphere (`src.main.core_prj...`).

To instruct semgrep to ignore the line, append an inline comment `nosem`, like the following for Python

```
>>> channel_module = importlib.import_module("src.main.core_prj.prj_" + config['subscription'].lower())  # nosem
```

Test the above in the semgrep rule playground at https://semgrep.dev/s/KXZL

After adding these inline comments disabling lines, or specific rules on lines, they can be shown again by using the `--strict` command-line argument.