# Suppressing cmd warning message

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, cmd2

When entering a shell I always get the following warning message from `cmd2`:

```
Desktop david$ python3 client.py
Readline features including tab completion have been disabled because
no supported version of readline was found. To resolve this, install
pyreadline on Windows or gnureadline on Mac.
```

This is something I know, and I'm not looking for or looking to fix that issue. Is there an option to suppress this error message with `cmd2` ? By the way, here is where the warning message comes from: https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2/blob/f5af7d32fb468012f793eb039e05a86292e0e5bf/cmd2/cmd2.py#L132-L146.

Comment: It's not an error message.

Comment: @12944qwerty sure, a [warning](https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2/blob/master/cmd2/rl_utils.py#L151).

Comment: If it is a warning you can likely suppress it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

Comment: @JonSG yea I tried that approach, It didn't seem to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than suppressing warnings (not great practice), why not just pip install `pyreadline` (Windows) or `gnureadline` (Mac) to fix the issue?

If you insist on suppressing the warning, something like

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Readline features including tab completion have been disabled")
```

would likely work.

I highly recommend not suppressing all warnings.