# PIL remove error "UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am running a code which takes an image an changes it to RGB format using `im.convert("RGB")`. However, when I run this, it prints in the terminal `UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images`, which, although it doesn't stop the program, is annoying and pops up every time. Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: Lots of possibilities here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/14463277/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell ah thanks I didn't know quite what to search for!

Answer (score 2):

Convert images to RGBA

```
for image in os.listdir(path/to/img/dir):
  im = Image.open(image)
  # If is png image
  if im.format is 'PNG':
    # and is not RGBA
    if im.mode is not 'RGBA':
      im.convert("RGBA").save(f"{image}2.png")
```

[reference](https://forums.fast.ai/t/errors-when-training-the-bear-image-classification-model/83422/13)

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'Image' is not defined`.  Does it need to be imported?

Comment: Yes, you need to import it, use the following code.
from PIL import Image

Answer (score 0):

The warning no longer seems a mere warning, but my images were no longer read.  I had to add the option `pilmode='RGBA'` in my code below to make it work again:

```py
import imageio.v3 as iio
img = iio.imread('file.png', pilmode='RGBA')
```