# panda df not showing all rows after loading from MS SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm using *Pandas* with latest *sqlalchemy* (`1.4.36`) to query a MS SQL DB, using the following Python `3.10.3` [Win] snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd                                             # 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
# ...
def get_table_columns():
    SQLA = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE \'pa%\' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;' 

    # Use pandas for getting named table & columns
    conn_str = set_db_info()
    conn_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": conn_str})
    engine = create_engine(conn_url)

    df = pd.read_sql(SQLA, engine)

    # Permanently changes the pandas settings
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    print(df)
    return df
```

However, this only prints the first 292 rows, and not all of the entire 2351 rows. Using REPL, I can check this with:

```py
>>> z = get_table_columns()
>>> z
                TABLE_NAME        COLUMN_NAME
0                    paacc           accesscd
... # <-- I added these
292                paapepi        piapeheadat

>>> z.count()
TABLE_NAME     2351
COLUMN_NAME    2351
dtype: int64

>>> z.shape[0]
2351

>>> z.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2351 entries, 0 to 2350
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------       --------------  -----
 0   TABLE_NAME   2351 non-null   object
 1   COLUMN_NAME  2351 non-null   object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 36.9+ KB
```

---

**Q:  What is going on, and why can't I print/show all the rows?**

Comment: can you try     pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10) to see if it works

Comment: @DataSciRookie I already tried that with 3000.

Comment: did you try to put out those lines from your functions ?  : pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

Comment: It's weird also, why don't we see your print(df) from your function when you call it ?

Comment: I see it, but it only shows the 1st 292 rows.

Comment: Did you try also : print("The value of max_rows : " +
      str(pd.get_option("display.max_rows")))
to check

Comment: Could this be a bug, due to the Unicide issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067094/pyodbc-deprecation-warning-when-printing) and reported [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/1002)? `PyUnicode_FromUnicode(NULL, size) is deprecated`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244537/discussion-between-not2qubit-and-datascirookie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that pandas returns a *packed* dataframe (DF). So when printing you only get a partial (at best) or broken (at worst) strings from the data.

For some reason this is always on by default and the results varies widely as to how much of the string/data that is shown. The solution is to use the *unpacking* operator (**`*`**) before/when trying to print the *df*, like this:

```py
print(*df)
```

(This is also know as the *splat* operator for Ruby enthusiasts.)

---

**References & tutorials**:

- https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-star-or-asterisk-operator/
- https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558
- https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480

Answer (score 1):

To display all the rows in pandas, you should set the display option to None or 1 extra from the dataframe size as you have done in your code:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', z.shape[0]+1)
```

Given that this is not the problem, it may be that the IDE or program that you use automatically crops this information from the view (For example Ipython crops every big output).

Other thing to try is to force the print of the dataframe instead of just is return value:

```
>>> print(z)
```

To inspect everything I would recommend you to pass that into a csv/excel file to do it better.

Comment: I'm using latest *Powershell Core* (pwsh) for UI, so not related at all.

Comment: But what program are you running your code in? python directly? ipdb? That is probably the one limiting your output for the return value of z, not the UI.