# Package win32 deprecation warning (pytest)

Tags: python, pytest, pywin32, xlwings

I'm running `pytest` on my project and I have the following warnings:

```
================================================== warnings summary ===================================================
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:51
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:51
  C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:51: DeprecationWarning: getargs: The 'u' format is deprecated. Use 'U' instead.
    found = _win32sysloader.GetModuleFilename(filename)

..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:65
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:65
  C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:65: DeprecationWarning: getargs: The 'u' format is deprecated. Use 'U' instead.
    found = _win32sysloader.LoadModule(filename)
```

I think it's about the package `win32` because of the path (`site-packages\win32\lib`) but I'm not sure what I should do. I believe I have this warning because I'm using `xlwings` which says it needs `pywin32`: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html.

I cannot afford to have warnings in my pytest output, what should I do? I can't really change the package locally (1/ because i don't know what effects it could have to use 'u' instead of 'U' 2/ my project has to not have warnings wherever I install it).

EDIT: I'm not allowed to simply ignore warnings.
EDIT2: Updating `pywin32` fixed the issue regarding the warnings, but now I have the following messages (even though pytest says successful):

```py
unit_tests\test_eplet_conversion.py Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706be

Current thread 0x000046cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests\test_eplet_conversion.py", line 27 in test_eplet_conversion
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests.py", line 3 in <module>
Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706ba

Current thread 0x000046cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests\test_eplet_conversion.py", line 27 in test_eplet_conversion
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests.py", line 3 in <module>
Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706ba

Current thread 0x000046cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests\test_eplet_conversion.py", line 27 in test_eplet_conversion
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests.py", line 3 in <module>
Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706ba

Current thread 0x000046cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests.py", line 3 in <module>
Windows fatal exception: code 0x800706ba

Current thread 0x000046cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322 in _main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File "C:\Users\lhott\Documents\Formation scolaire\These\Travail\SagaGL\SAgA\SAgA 1.00\src\viewers\BasicAntibodyAnalysisViewer\unit_tests.py", line 3 in <module>
```

This is something I have no idea what to do about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Comment: No. I don't want to disable the warnings. I want to fix them. I'm not allowed to ignore warnings (whether it's with #noqa for the IDE warnings or the logger warings). I edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: You want to fix the warnings without changing the code that causes them?

Comment: Yes, maybe by prompting the creators of pywin32 to do something about it (so that pip install -U pywin32 fixes it everywhere my code is  used). But I'm not even sure my analysis is correct. Which is why i'm posting here.

Comment: Please post your (minimum amount of) code required to reproduce the problem. **[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.