# How to capture console output from xarray.open_dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray, console-output

When accessing remote datasets with `xarray.open_dataset`, warnings or errors sometimes show up in my console.

Capturing messages written to `sys.stderr` or `sys.stdout` is certainly possible (or one can also add some [warnings management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) as @MichaelDelgado suggested):

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import xarray as xr

url = "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:80/dods/gefs/gefs20220909/gec00_00z_pgrb2a"

try:
    sys.stderr = err = StringIO()
    ds = xr.open_dataset(url_not_exist)
    print(ds.dims)
except OSError as ose:
    print(f"Error Log = {ose}", file=sys.stderr)
finally:
    sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
    if err.tell() > 0:
        err.seek(0)
        print(f"Additional Info: " + err.read())
```

->

```
Frozen({'ens': 1, 'time': 65, 'lev': 12, 'lat': 361, 'lon': 720})
Additional Info: /home/workspace/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/coding/times.py:144: SerializationWarning: Ambiguous reference date string: 1-1-1 00:00:0.0. The first value is assumed to be the year hence will be padded with zeros to remove the ambiguity (the padded reference date string is: 0001-1-1 00:00:0.0). To remove this message, remove the ambiguity by padding your reference date strings with zeros.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, SerializationWarning)
```

**Note:** Be aware that the URL I used only is valid for some days. if you want to try it out, change the date that the path contains (/gefs.../) to a more recent one.

### But...

In other cases redirecting stderr has no effect. For example, when the url references a non-existent resource.
Setting `url = "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:80/dods/gefs/DOES_NOT_EXIST/gec00_00z_pgrb2a"` and executing the same code gives:

```
oc_open: server error retrieving url: code=0 message="/gefs/asdf/gec00_00z_pgrb2a is not an available dataset"
Additional Info: Error Log = [Errno -70] NetCDF: DAP server error: b'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:80/dods/gefs/asdf/gec00_00z_pgrb2a'
```

As you can see, some info has been written to the console and one has no handle on it. It is **not** written to `stdout` or `stderr` and this can potentially clutter the logs or just be missing in the actual logs.

I'd like to understand what happens here. Is xarray spawning a subprocess that has no idea about the sys.stderr situation? How can I properly log these messages or at least avoid them to clutter the console?

Comment: Is it possible that that error is actually being output to `stdout`?

Comment: does normal [warnings management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) not do the trick? the error is a properly raise warning: see [`xarray/coding/times.py`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/main/xarray/coding/times.py#L143-L150)

Comment: @pigrammer, I did also re-route `stout` for testing but no success...

Comment: @MichaelDelgado - I did some testing and can now with certainty say that the code example handles messages that are written to `stderr` and `stdout` correctly. With that it also captures the messages in e.g. [times.py](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/main/xarray/coding/times.py#L143-L150). 
Other messages must show up in the console through some other route. I am clarifying this in my question...