# How do i get rid of pysdl-dll user warning?

Tags: python

- I have installed sdl2 and sdl2-dll packages from pip and imported them.
- Created a simple window and application loop.

But every time i run the application, i get an annoying user warning that says :

`UserWarning: Using SDL2 binaries from pysdl2-dll 2.26.1`

I tried using `warnings.catch_warnings` but it doesn't seem to work :(

How do i get rid of it and is there any environment variable that might solve my problem ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings) help?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you :)
I found out that there is an interpreter option called "-W ignore" which ignores the warning.