# Databricks Community Error: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

Whenever I execute any code on Databricks Community Edition with "is" I get the following error:

```
SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
```

For example, the following code will generate the error:

```
if len(chkRows) is 0:
```

I have done some research and I believe the issue is with Python 3.8.

How can I overcome this situation without having to re-code all of my work? All of my code is set up in my Python wheel, and I can't find the original code.

I changed the code from "is" to "==", but I get the same error

```
<command-4177784089769769>:15: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(pkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:23: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(chkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:15: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(pkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:23: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(chkRows) == 0:
```

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Yes, you did mean `==`. You don't care if it's the exact same object, just that its an integer with zero value. `is` works consistently only because small integers are _interned_, that's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I'm not my desk at the moment but I get a similar error message when I enter ==   You're probably think I'm being lazy. When I get back to my desk I'll let you know what the error is when I replace 0 with ==  But just know replacing with == gives an error

Comment: Back at my desk. So I change from "is" to "==", but I get the exact same error ``<command-4177784089769769>:15: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(pkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:23: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(chkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:15: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(pkRows) == 0:
<command-4177784089769769>:23: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if len(chkRows) == 0:``

Comment: Hello all, please may I get some guidance on how to fix this please.

Comment: That's an interesting issue. Can you share how you define `chkRows`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] -- steps someone else can follow without changes to see the same problem _after `is` is no longer in use_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Python warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)