# How to change the tkinter icon when using tqdm.tk for a GUI progress bar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tqdm

I have this python function that downloads a file and shows the progress bar using tqdm.tk. Now I'm getting the default tkinter icon and I want to change it. How would I do it?

```
import requests
import os
from tqdm.tk import tqdm

def download_update(url, destination):
   response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))

   print('Update in Progress (Make sure the connection is stable)\n')

   with open(destination, 'wb') as file, tqdm(
       desc='Update in Progress',
       total=total_size,
       unit='B',
       unit_scale=True,
       unit_divisor=1024,  #1024
       colour= '#f8b4aa',
   ) as bar:
       for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): #1024
           size = file.write(data)
           bar.update(size)
```

[image]

And I get a default warning message in the console which says *TqdmExperimentalWarning: GUI is experimental/alpha* when I use tqdm.tk. How can I disable it?

Comment: maybe check in documentation for `tqdm.tk` if it gives direct access to `tkinter` Window . And later use `window.iconbitmap(...)` or `window.wm_iconphoto(...)`

Comment: if you will run it as any other GUI program - clicking on icon without running console - then you will not see message and you don't have to bother this.

Comment: see source code for [tqdm.tk](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/tk.py) - you can see it keeps `tkinter.Tk()` as `self._tk_window` so you can try to use `bar._tk_window.iconbitmap(...)`

Comment: source code also shows that you may first create `window = tkinter.Tk()` and later send it to `tqdm(..., tk_parent=window)`, and this allow you to set icon directly to `window`

Comment: PS. [How to disable Python warnings? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code for [tqdm.tk](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/tk.py) shows that it keeps main window `tkinter.Tk()` as `self._tk_window` so you can try to use

```
bar._tk_window.iconbitmap("myIcon.ico")
```

or

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open('image.jpg')    # or `.png`
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

bar._tk_window.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you may also first create own window, next set icon, and next send this window to `tqdm.tk` but it creates `tqdm` as second window (`tk.Toplevel()`) and icon will be assigned to main window. So it still needs to use `bar._tk_window`

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.iconbitmap("main_windown.ico")  # or `window.wm_iconphoto(...)

with ...., tqdm.tk(..., tk_parent=window) as bar:
    bar._tk_window.iconbitmap("progressbar.ico")  # or `window.wm_iconphoto(...)

    # .... rest ...
    bar.update(...)
```

---

Full working example. It needs only some `image.png`.

```
import time 
from tqdm.tk import tqdm
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

size = 10

with tqdm(total=size) as bar:
    #bar._tk_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    image = Image.open('image.png')    # or `.jpg`
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    bar._tk_window.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)

    for _ in range(size):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        bar.update(1)
```