# Unexpected division by zero warning when using np.where

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to numpy and trying to replace for loops using `np.where`. What I am trying to achieve is simple, I have 4 different conditions and based on these conditions, I am assigning values to elements of the array:

```
Period = np.arange(0.0,8.0,0.01)

Ta = 0.075
Tb = 0.375
Tl = 6.0
Sds = 1.2
Sd1 = 0.45

Sae = np.zeros(len(Period))
Sae = np.where((Period>=0.0) & (Period<=Ta),0.4+0.6*(Period/Ta)*Sds,Sae)
Sae = np.where((Period>=Ta) & (Period<=Tb),Sds,Sae)
Sae = np.where((Period>=Tb) & (Period<=Tl),Sd1/Period,Sae)
Sae = np.where((Period>=Tl),Sd1*Tl/Period**2,Sae)
```

And I get RuntimeWarning:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  Sae = np.where((Period>=Tb) & (Period<=Tl),Sd1/Period,Sae)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  Sae = np.where((Period>=Tl),Sd1*Tl/Period**2,Sae)
```

I know `Period` array starts with 0.0, but imposed conditions should avoid running into division by zero.

However, there is nothing wrong with the resultant `Sae` array. Still I would like not to see division by zero warning.

Thanks!

Comment: The first element of `Period` is `0.0`. Then you do `something/Period`.

Comment: But I should never get ```something/0.0``` because of the conditions.

Comment: @timgeb but it is just in the places where Period>=Tb, which is greater than 0.

Comment: Function arguments get evaluated before the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `arr1 / arr2` is evaluated before the call to `np.where()`, hence NumPy is wisely warning you of the potential issue.

If you are absolutely sure that your warning does not apply to you, you can just ignore it for the culprit line(s), e.g.:

```
with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    # The problematic line(s)
    Sae = np.where((Period>=Tl),Sd1*Tl/Period**2,Sae)
    ...
```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9134795/5218354).

Alternatively you could just avoid dividing by zero with an appropriate mask.
For example, this line:

```
Sae = np.where((Period>=Tl),Sd1*Tl/Period**2,Sae)
```

would become:

```
mask = Period > 0
temp = np.zeros_like(Period)
temp[mask] = Sd1*Tl/Period[mask]**2
Sae = np.where((Period>=Tl),temp,Sae)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sae = np.where((Period>=Tb) & (Period<=Tl), Sd1/Period, Sae)
```

is equivalent to

```
if_mask = (Period>=Tb) & (Period<=Tl)
then = Sd1/Period
else_ = Sae
Sae = np.where(if_mask, then, else_)
```

You are dividing by zero in `Sd1/Period` because the first element of `Period` is `0.0`.