# Disable warning when using end user credentials in GCP scripts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running some scripts to do some ad-hoc jobs in GCP, using the **Python client libraries**.
These are ad-hoc and thus I believe they should be run on my end user credentials instead of a service account.

I keep seeing this warning and it makes it hard to debug my script standard output:

```
UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK without a quota project. You might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. We recommend you rerun `gcloud auth application-default login` and make sure a quota project is added. Or you can use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
```

I did the suggested `gcloud auth application-default login` but the same warning message still appears repeatedly.

How do I disable this warning?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I'm understanding your question. If you'd like to disable all warnings you could always take advantage of the [--verbosity flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) and run every command with the flag set to `error` (e.g. gcloud auth init --verbosity="error"). Running `gcloud config set core/verbosity error` would update the value on your [default configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations#default_configuration) and all gcloud commands that you run would be using that verbosity level by default.

Comment: If you don't find the comment above to be useful please post a minimum, reproducible example of your specific script without sharing any sensible data as well as a brief explanation of what your script does. I recommend you to through [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) that gives some useful advise when scripting with gcloud commands.

Comment: I think I should have mentioned, I am using the Python client library

Comment: Editing your post to include a minimum reproducible example of your script code might be of use! The [Python client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries) handle all the low level authentication based on environment variables or pointing to a file with the specific credentials for a service account. Are you using [google-auth¶](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/index.html)

Comment: @DanielOcando what happened to my comment? Hmmm

Comment: To anyone coming to this question, if you wish to resolve that specific warning and not **disable all warnings** ignore the suggestions made by @DanielOcando above and check out the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [the lines in the library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/bc92abbce5e0a5e7b5de8157e7772db84349a6cb/google/auth/_default.py#L50-L70). The message is hardcoded into the function named `_warn_about_problematic_credentials` (starting on line 59).

If you go [deeper into the file](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/bc92abbce5e0a5e7b5de8157e7772db84349a6cb/google/auth/_default.py#L126-L127), you can see that the warning message is displayed only if there isn't a quota project defined.

You may use the following command to add a quota project to your application-default credentials:

```
gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project <YOUR PROJECT ID>
```

Comment: To complement this answer here is the relevant documentation for the [set-quota-project command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project). Notice that you must first run gcloud auth application-default login in order  to generate the application default credentials and the existing application default credentials must have at least the "serviceusage.services.use" permission assigned.

Comment: This works for me. I accepted this over my answer as this is less hacky than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to disable this simply by using a Python ignore warning option as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings).

```
python3 -W ignore my_script.py
```

If you want to be more precise and only disable certain warnings you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134795/how-to-get-rid-of-specific-warning-messages-in-python-while-keeping-all-other-wa).