# Geopandas warning on read_file()

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm getting the following warning reading a geojson with geopanda's read_file():

```
...geodataframe.py:422: RuntimeWarning: Sequential read of iterator was interrupted. Resetting iterator. This can negatively impact the performance.
  for feature in features_lst:
```

Here's the code sample I used:

```
crime_gdf = gpd.read_file('datasets/crimes.geojson', bbox=bbox)
```

`crimes.geojson` is a file containing a large number of points, each with a 'Crime type'

`bbox` defines the boundaries

The code runs as expected, but I don't understand that warning.

**EDIT**

I converted the geojson to feather, and I get the same warning.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is writing to or otherwise using that file?

Comment: Yes, the file is being used just by this script

Comment: It's in a Google Drive folder. Can that be the reason?

Comment: I have no idea, you could just move it out of Google Drive and see if that helps

Comment: It runs with the same warning outside the Google Drive folder

Comment: Here is a hint to the provenience of the `RuntimeWarning`: I get it when using `list(src)` on a GPKG opened by Fiona 1.8.18. Looks like a regression. I don't get the warning in 1.8.13.

Comment: What's your fiona version?

Comment: Also no problem in 1.8.17.

Comment: My fiona version is 1.8.18

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See my comment in Fiona's issue tracker: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/986

GDAL (the library Fiona uses to access the geodata) maintains an iterator over the features that are currently read. There a some operations that, for some drivers, can influence this iterator. Thus, after such operations we have to ensure that the iterator is set to the correct position that a continuous read of the data is ensured. Such operations include counting all features in a dataset, respectively calculating its extent.

There are different types of drivers in GDAL. Some drivers support random access, while some do not. For the drivers that do not support random access, the resetting of the iterator involves reading all features again up to the iterator position. As this is a possible costly operation, this RuntimeWarning is emitted, so that users are aware of this behavior.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance in this issue, but is it possible for me to select a driver that support random access?

Comment: @leosole It depends on the file you are reading. There is one driver for GeoJSON, one for GPKG, etc. So you cannot use another driver for GeoJSON.

Comment: I see. I can convert the file to something else. I tried converting to feather, but the warning persists

Comment: @leosole This is just a warning. If you do not see any performance-related issues you can safely ignore it. I suspect with geopandas it is the the same issue as with list(src). If this is the case the warning should probably not be raised anyway.  In https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/986 you will find more information about why list() causes this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I found this `fiona` PR that references the warning: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/pull/965

I can reproduce the issue with `fiona` 1.8.18 when calling `list(src)` on a recently opened `Collection`, but not with 1.8.17. So I think this is a regression that was introduced in `fiona` 1.8.18, released on 2020-11-17.

Answer (score 3):

While it could cause problems ignoring warnings in some contexts, I am finding this one particularly annoying repeated in my code output.

I found the warning can be ignored using

```
import warnings
# filter out RuntimeWarnings, due to geopandas/fiona read file spam
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995369/geopandas-warning-on-read-file
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=RuntimeWarning)
```

I added in the comments referencing this post to explain why I am filtering out these warnings.  When this warning is suppressed in a future geopandas / fiona release then this code snippet should probably be removed, as it may also suppress meaningful warnings and could be problematic in some contexts.

Comment: See this answer for how to be more specific about which warnings to suppress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134842/4742780