# pytorch reduce_op warning message despite not calling it

Tags: pytorch

I'm constantly receiving a warning message per below; despite not calling the pytorch reduce_op anywhere.

```
C:\Users\cocoj\.conda\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\distributed_c10d.py:170: UserWarning: torch.distributed.reduce_op is deprecated, please use torch.distributed.ReduceOp instead
  warnings.warn(
```

I have found the below link; however not clear what the OP suggested as solution.

https://github.com/ucbrise/flor/issues/57

my pytorch is most uptodate per conda list:

```
pytorch                   1.10.0          py3.9_cuda11.3_cudnn8_0    pytorch
```

Answer (score 4):

I am also not clear on what they meant, but since they were saying that it's safe to ignore you can try using the warnings module to ignore the message like so:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="torch.distributed.reduce_op is deprecated")
```

Note that it will ignore anything **containing** the string in the 'message' argument, so use with caution if you don't enter the full error message.

You can also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134795/how-to-get-rid-of-specific-warning-messages-in-python-while-keeping-all-other-wa), which has a similar solution.