# Importing and Using NLTK corpus

Tags: python, nltk

Please, please, please help. I have a folder filled with text files that I want to use NLTK to analyze. How do I import that as a corpus and then run NLTK commands on it? I've put together the code below but it's giving me this error:

```
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Code:

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpus_root = '/Users/jt/Documents/Python/CRspeeches'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '*.txt')

print "Finished importing corpus" 

words = FreqDist()

for sentence in speeches.sents():
    for word in sentence:
        words.inc(word.lower())

print words["he"]
print words.freq("he")
```

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on. In short, **where** do you have an error? Please include the full error trace for starters, then go over your program step by step. Does your corpus consist of `.txt` files in the directory `CRspeeches`? After initializing `speeches`, do you get a list of your files with `print(speeches.fileids())`? Can you _print_ some of the sentences that should be returned by `speeches.sents()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand this problem has to do with a known [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue2537) (maybe it's a feature?), which is partially explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3675144/1141805). In short, certain regexes about empty things blow up.

The source of the error is you `speeches =` line. You should change it to the following:

```
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, r'.*\.txt')
```

Then everything will load  and compile just fine.

Comment: Do I have to keep loading the corpus whenever I use it or can I now just write import speeches at the top of my nltk scripts?

Comment: Well spotted, @mixedmath! But it's not a bug: A regexp that starts with `*` is malformed. (The error message could have been more informative, though.)

Comment: Let's clarify: `*.txt`, which the OP tried, is a _glob_ that matches all files with the extension `.txt`. But the NLTK's corpus readers don't accept globs, they accept full regular expressions. @mixedmath's solution translates @Jolijt's glob to the equivalent regexp, `.*\.txt`.