# "Nothing to repeat" from Python regex

Tags: python, regex

Here is a regex - attempted by egrep and then by Python 2.7:

> $ echo '/some/path/to/file/abcde.csv' | egrep '*([a-zA-Z]+).csv'
>
> /some/path/to/file/**abcde.csv**

However, the same regex in Python:

```
re.match(r'*([a-zA-Z]+)\.csv',f )
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/OpenChai/bin/plothost.py", line 26, in <module>
    hosts = [re.match(r'*([a-zA-Z]+)\.csv',f ).group(1) for f in infiles]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Doing a search reveals there appears to be a Python bug in play here:

[regex error - nothing to repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat)

> It seems to be a python bug (that works perfectly in vim). The source
>   of the problem is the (\s*...)+ bit.

However, it is not clear to me: what then is the workaround for my regex shown above - to make ***python*** happy?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `.*` or `.*?` ?

Comment: It's not a python bug; you have a `*` (which means 'the previous character repeated 0 or more times') without a previous character.

Comment: `*` in regex means `0 or more of the previous` so what you're complaining is a bug isn't a bug at all.  What do you want that `*` to match?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not need the `*` in the pattern, it causes the issue because you are trying to quantify the beginning of the pattern, but there is nothing, an *empty string*, to quantify.

The same "*`Nothing to repeat`*" error occurs when you

- Place *any* quantifier (`+`, `?`, `*`, `{2}`, `{4,5}`, etc.) at the start of the pattern (e.g. `re.compile(r'?')`)
- Add any quantifier right after `^` / `\A` start of string anchor (e.g. `re.compile(r'^*')`)
- Add any quantifier right after `$` / `\Z` end of string anchor (e.g. `re.compile(r'$*')`)
- Add any quantifier after a word boundary (e.g.`re.compile(r'\b*\d{5}')`)

Note, however, that in Python `re`, you may quantify any lookaround, e.g. `(?<!\d)*abc` and `(?<=\d)?abc` will yield the same matches since the lookarounds are optional.

Use

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\.csv
```

Or to match the whole string:

```
.*([a-zA-Z]+)\.csv
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO3iZ6/1)

The reason is that `*` is unescaped and is thus treated as a quantifier. It is applied to the preceding subpattern in the regex. Here, it is used in the beginning of a pattern, and thus cannot quantify nothing. Thus, **nothing to repeat** is thrown.

If it "works" in VIM, it is just because VIM regex engine ignores this subpattern (same as Java does with unescaped `[` and `]` inside a character class like `[([)]]`).

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug python regex engine use traditional NFA for matching patterns. and character `*` just works when precede by a token.

> `'*'`
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the **preceding** RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

So instead you can use `.*` which repeat any character (`.`) :

```
r'.*([a-zA-Z]+)\.csv'
```

Also python provide the module [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) which support Unix shell-style wildcards.

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> s="/some/path/to/file/abcde.csv"
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch(s, '*.csv')
True
```