# Negative pattern matching Reg ex In Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regular-language

Tryto use negative forward to replace all string which does not match a pattern:

```
regexPattern = '((?!*' + 'word1|word2|word3' + ').)*$'  
mytext= 'jsdjsqd word1dsqsqsword2fjsdjswrod3sqdq'
return re.sub(regexPattern, "P", mytext)

#Expected Correct Output:  'PPPPPPword1PPPPPPword2PPPPPword3PPP'

#BAD Output:  'jsdjsqd word1dsqsqsword2fjsdjswrod3sqdq'
```

I try this but it does not work (string remains same). 
How to modify it ? (think this is pretty difficult regex)

Comment: post a sample data along with expected output.

Comment: remove `*` in `'((?!*'`

Comment: You want to replace all strings that do not contain `word1` or `word2` or `word3`? [`r'(?s)^(?!.*(?:word1|word2|word3)).*$'`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ5tF3/1). *it does not work well* - how does it work for you, what is the problem?

Comment: The code above throws a well known [*nothing to repeat* error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat).

Comment: Your code submitted seems not working too. Any idea ?

Comment: @quantCode: What code? What does not work? The `My text with word1` string contains `word1` and thus is not matched. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/FVb2Gh). `r'(?s)^(?!.*(?:word1|word2|word3)).*$'` matches any string that has no `word1`, `word2` or `word3` in it.

Comment: r'(?s)^(?!.*(?:word1|word2|word3)).*$'   this one, Be careful , this is for substiution (not search, also this is in Python (so regex are different).

Comment: Your code r'(?s)^(?!.*(?:word1|word2|word3)).*$'   does  not work. It returns "jsdjsqd word1dsqsqsword2fjsdjswrod3sqdq" . Nothing was replaced.

Comment: You should have added the requirement: *any character should be replaced with `P` and the `word1`, `word2`, and `word3` character sequences should remain intact*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(word1|word2|word3)|.', re.S)
mytext = 'jsdjsqd word1dsqsqsword2fjsdjsword3sqdq'
print(regex.sub(lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "P", mytext))
// => PPPPPPPPword1PPPPPPword2PPPPPPword3PPPP
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/H0BK39)

The regex is `(word1|word2|word3)|.`:

- `(word1|word2|word3)` - either `word1`, or `word2`, or `word3` character sequences
- `|` - or...
- `.` - any character (incl. a newline as `re.S` DOTALL mode is on)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF3kJ2/1)

Comment: Ok, If we want this output: 'Pword1Pword2Pword3P' , do we nee to do another step ?

Comment: You can use a tempered greedy token like you have: [`re.compile(r'(word1|word2|word3)|(?:(?!word1|word2|word3).)*', re.S)`](https://ideone.com/Xpm1Pn)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two-stage approach: First, replace the characters that *do* match with some special character, then use that as a mask to replace all the *other* characters.

```
>>> text= 'jsdjsqd word1dsqsqsword2fjsdjsword3sqdq'
>>> p = 'word1|word2|word3'
>>> mask = re.sub(p, lambda m: 'X' * len(m.group()), text)
>>> mask
'jsdjsqd XXXXXdsqsqsXXXXXfjsdjsword3sqdq'
>>> ''.join(t if m == 'X' else 'P' for (t, m) in zip(text, mask))
'PPPPPPPPword1PPPPPPword2PPPPPPword3PPPP'
```

Of course, instead of `X` you might have to choose a different character, that does not occur in the original string.