# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object python re package

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to count the number of existing words of my string list in a column dataframe for each row.

code:

```
   list_1 = ['Apple', 'Mango' ,'Orange', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
   list_2 = ['weather', 'r[ea]d' ,'p[wr]iority', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
   list_3 = ['n[eéè]d','snow[s]?', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
   dict = {"s1":['Column_1', list_1],
                    "s2": ['Column_1', list_3],
                    "s3": ['Column_2', list_2],
                    "s4": ['Column_3', list_3],
                    "s5": ['Column_2','Column_3',list_1],}

  for elt in list(dict.keys()):
    if len(dict[elt])<=2:
        d = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][1]).lower(), df[dict[elt][0]].str.lower()))
        df[elt] = sum(d.values()) 
    elif len(dict[elt])>2:
        aa = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][2]).lower(), df[dict[elt][0]].str.lower()))
        bb = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][2]).lower(), df[dict[elt][1]].str.lower()))
        b = sum(bb.values()) 
        a = sum(aa.values()) 
        d = a +b 
        df[elt] = d
```

Example of data:

```
     d = {'Column_1': ['mango pret Orange No manner', ' préts  No scan'],  'Column_2': ['read priority No', 'This is a priority'],'Column_3': ['No add', 'yep']}
     df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

     d2 = {'s1': [3, 1], 's3':[2,1]}
     df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

but i got this erro ... **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

Comment: I get an error here: `list(dict.keys())`. Do you mean `dicti`? And what is `df`? I suppose some kind of data frame.

Comment: yep its dict .. sorry

Comment: @George i Edited my original post

Comment: `str(df[dict[elt][0]].str.lower())` and apply that every time you call `re.findall`. In `re.findall` you are looking for a `str` in an `object`. That fixes your original error.

Comment: @George now i got this error **error: nothing to repeat at position 188**

Comment: As is with that fix, other errors appear due to the fact that there is no `Column_3` in the example data you provided. Therefore I don't know if that fixes your problem. I can't replicate it, if you don't provide a MWE.

Comment: what i provided is jus an exemple that i created ..

Comment: Yes but the error I get is: `KeyError: 'Column_3'`, because there is no column 3 in `df`. Therefore I can't replicate your error, with insufficient code. However, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat) can help you.

Comment: @George post edited

Comment: OK, so `'Column_3'` you added has 3 elements instead of 2, so it produces an error since the arrays are of different size. But after fixing that, it works for me. Are you running a python version previous to 2.7.6?

Comment: @George i have version 3.6

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (python version 3.6.8):

```
d = {'Column_1': ['mango pret Orange No manner', ' préts  No scan'],  'Column_2': ['read priority No', 'This is a priority'],'Column_3': ['No add', 'yep']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'s1': [3, 1], 's3':[2,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

list_1 = ['Apple', 'Mango' ,'Orange', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
list_2 = ['weather', 'r[ea]d' ,'p[wr]iority', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
list_3 = ['n[eéè]d','snow[s]?', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
dic = {"s1":['Column_1', list_1],
            "s2": ['Column_1', list_3],
            "s3": ['Column_2', list_2],
            "s4": ['Column_3', list_3],
            "s5": ['Column_2','Column_3',list_1],}

for elt in list(dic.keys()):
    if len(dic[elt])<=2:
        d = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dic[elt][1]).lower(), str(df[dic[elt][0]].str.lower())))
        df[elt] = sum(d.values()) 
    elif len(dic[elt])>2:
        aa = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dic[elt][2]).lower(), str(df[dic[elt][0]].str.lower())))
        bb = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dic[elt][2]).lower(), str(df[dic[elt][1]].str.lower())))
        b = sum(bb.values()) 
        a = sum(aa.values()) 
        d = a +b 
        df[elt] = d
```

Comment: @This, if this still produces the other error you mentioned, I suggest asking another question, referencing the new error you get.

Comment: it gives not same results like my df2