# How to get list of file's url using urllib.request?

Tags: python, python-re

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

urlpath =urlopen("http://blablabla.com/file")
string = urlpath.read().decode('utf-8')

pattern = re.compile('*.docx"')
onlyfiles = pattern.findall(string)

print(onlyfiles)
```

Target output

```
['http://blablabla.com/file/1.docx','http://blablabla.com/file/2.docx']
```

But I got this

```
[]
```

I get this error message when trying this.

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star from this line:

```
pattern = re.compile('*.docx"')
```

Apparently seems to be a python known bug:

Check out this related answers: [regex error - nothing to repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat)

Try this using *word* or *a-z* regexp:

```
pattern = re.compile('\w*.docx"')
# or
pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]*.docx"')
```