# How can I fix re.error: nothing to repeat at position 14?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

First, I am aware that it has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675144/regex-error-nothing-to-repeat), but it is really old so the bug might be fixed. Here is my question:

I am writing a program to remove all symbols from a string. Here is my code:

```py
text = input("Enter some text ")
symbols = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '=', '{', '}', '|', '[', ']', ':', '\\', '"', ';', "'", '<', '>', '?', ',', '.', '/']
text = re.sub("|".join(symbols), "", text)
print(text)
```

When I run this, I get `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 14`. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to regex-escape those characters, some of them (`*` is the first one causing the error in this specific case) have actual meaning. You can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), for example, although it's a touch over-zealous. I'd recommend using https://regex101.com/r/JOjEAb/1 first when you have regex issues - this *isn't* a bug in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How do I regex-escape them?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?

Comment: As @jonrsharpe says, have a read in the docs, and use an online regex parser to see whats actually happening. `*` in regex means 0 or more times, but it applies to the previous value, in your regex you end up with `|*|` so you say or 0 or more times but there is no expression to apply this repeat to. You need to regex escape all your symbols like `text = re.sub("|".join([re.escape(symbol) for symbol in symbols]), "", text)`